# Why do I get c2039 compiler error after changing condition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a problem with compiling my code in Visual Studio:

```cpp
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

namespace twnd{

 namespace res{

  class DrawObj{
  private:
   //members...
   twnd::Window* GetParent();

  public:
   //functions...

  }

 }

 class Window{
  priate:
  //members...
  twnd::res::DrawObj draw_obj;
  public:
  //functions...
 }

}
```

Every time I try to compile this code, I get dozens of compiler errors, but I think the main problem is the error `C2039` that states:

> Window is not member of twnd

The code was working before, I just changed some conditions.

Some other errors that I get:

```
C2143: missing ; in front of *
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C2671: static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
C2039: 'function name' is not a member of twnd::res::DrawObj
```

I thought that somewhere in the included header files, there might be something named the same way as my namespaces or classes, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Please create a [mre] to show us. And please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log from the shown example. And add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Also remember that symbols must be declared *before* they are used. If you have a circular dependency like you do, then use *forward declarations* to solve that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `twnd::Window` before it has been declared.

Also, you have a few typos in the code shown.

Try this:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

namespace twnd{

 class Window; // <-- ADD THIS

 namespace res{

  class DrawObj{
  private:
   //members...
   twnd::Window* GetParent();

  public:
   //functions...

  }; // <-- ADD semicolon

 }

 class Window{
  private: // <-- FIX TYPO
   //members...
   twnd::res::DrawObj draw_obj;
  public:
   //functions...
 }; // <-- ADD SEMICOLON

}
```